# Angular 5 -> Inputfield from Arrayentry

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I have an Array of all my Articles.

So I have another Array for the Basket Values. I filtered my Article Array with Product types. So when I add an Article to the Basket and I switch the Product types that work. But when i switch back to the other Products the Inputfield is empty. So i cannot edit my Basket. I only can delete the Basketentry and add a new one. Is there a Way to get the Pieces in the Input back from the Basketentry?

This is the call to become my Articles and the filter

```
getNagelplattenWithTyp() {
  if(this.nagelplatten == null) {
  this.ns.getNagelplatten().subscribe(data => this.nagelplatten = data);
}
}

filter(typ: string) {
    console.log("Filter:" + typ);
    this.nagelplattenFiltered === null;
    this. nagelplattenFiltered = this.nagelplatten.filter((nagel: Nagelplatten) => 
    nagel.Bezeichnung1.indexOf(typ) > -1);
}
```

This is the function to add the Articel in the Basketarray

```
addToCart(stk, index, artnr, typ: string) {
   this.nagelplatten[index].Stk = stk;
   this.nagelplatten[index].Typ = typ;
   var sum = (this.nagelplatten[index].Preis * this.nagelplatten[index].Stk);
   this.nagelplatten[index].Gesamt = sum;

for (let i = 0; i < this.nagelplatten.length; i++) {
     if(this.nagelplatten[i].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.warenkorb.length; i++) {
        if(this.warenkorb[i].Stk == stk && this.warenkorb[i].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
          this.warenkorb.splice(i, 1);
        }

      }
       this.warenkorb.push(this.nagelplatten[index]);

       console.log("ArtNrcheck" + JSON.stringify(this.warenkorb));
      } 
      this.Gesamt = this.nagelplatten[i].Gesamt;
  }

      this.showBasket = true;
      this.calcSumme();
      this.calczwischensumme();
      console.log("Add to Warenkorb: " + JSON.stringify(this.warenkorb));   
}
```

this is my HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="filter('4941')">
                      <div class="row_accordion">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-5 col-xl-4">12N</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-4 text-right"> 2,38</div>
                          <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1 text-right">23,36</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
                      <div class="row_accordion">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                              <br>
                            <div *ngIf="!nagelplatten;then loading else show"></div>
                            <ng-template #loading>
                            <mat-progress-bar  mode="indeterminate" color="yellow"></mat-progress-bar>
                            Daten werden geladen ...
                          </ng-template>
                            <ng-template #show>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">Blechdicke: 1,25 mm</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"> Zulassungsnummer: Z-9.1-801</div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="buttonBasket" id="myHeader">
                                <button type="button" (click)="addToCart()">Übernehmen und Warenkorb berechnen</button>
                                <br></div>

                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="artWidthHeader col-lg-2 col-xl-2">Menge</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader2 col-lg-1 col-xl-2">Art.Nr.</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader2 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">Größe</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 col-lg-1 col-xl-2 text-right">kg/ME</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-right">ME</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 offset-xl-1 col-xl-1 text-right">Preis/ME</div>  
                            </div>
                            <table class="table">
                          <tr class="" *ngFor="let n of nagelplatten; let in = index; index as i; odd as isOdd; even as isEven" 
                          [ngClass]="{ odd: isOdd, even: isEven }" >
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="artWidth col-lg-2 col-xl-2"><span><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]" name='name' (change)="addToCart(name.value, in, n.PKArtikelID, '12N')" #name><div *ngIf="n.ME > 1;then karton else stueck"></div></span><ng-template #karton> Karton</ng-template>
                            <ng-template #stueck> Stück</ng-template></div>
                            <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2">{{ n.PKArtikelID }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-lg-1 col-xl-2">{{ n.Breite }} x {{ n.Laenge }} mm</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.Gewicht | number: '1.4-4' }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.ME }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.Preis | number: '1.4-4'}}</div>  
                          </div>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        </ng-template>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </ng-template>
                  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

Thx

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, reviewing your HTML-template I'd suggest the following solution:

1. extend your nagelpaletten-model by adding the field bestellmenge or just menge. e.g.

   ```
   export class nagelpaletten {
       constructor(
        bestellmenge: number,
        PKArtikelID: string,
        laenge: number,
        Gewicht: number,  
        ME: number,
        Preis: number
       ) {}
   }
   ```

Maybe your model is structured a little differently but mine is just supposed to give you a hint.

2. rework your HTML-template by binding the field 'bestellmenge' via [(ngModel)] to your input element:

   ```
   <table class="table">
     <tr class="" *ngFor="let n of nagelplatten; let in = index; index as i; odd as isOdd; even as isEven" 
        [ngClass]="{ odd: isOdd, even: isEven }" >
        <div class="row">
           <div class="artWidth col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
             <span>
               <input [(ngModel)]="n.bestellmenge" type="number" pattern="[0-9]" name='name' (change)="addToCart(name.value, in, n.PKArtikelID, '12N')" #name>
               <div *ngIf="n.ME > 1;then karton else stueck"></div>
             </span>
             <ng-template #karton> Karton</ng-template>
             <ng-template #stueck> Stück</ng-template>
          </div>
          <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2">{{ n.PKArtikelID }}</div>
          <div class="artikel col-lg-1 col-xl-2">{{ n.Breite }} x {{ n.Laenge }} mm</div>
          <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.Gewicht | number: '1.4-4' }}</div>
          <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.ME }}</div>
          <div class="artikel col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-right">{{ n.Preis | number: '1.4-4'}}</div>  
       </div>
   ```

As long as you do not reload the whole nagelpaletten-object from server(!), you will now have each Menge that has been entered directly stored in your nagelpaletten-object. Now it should be possible to visit the shopping basket and return without losing the entered values.

Attention, maybe now you have to care for removing those bestellmenge-values afterwards!

To solve your problem another way you were forced to create something like a wrapper object. That's more complicated and rather unnecessary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'i' twice!

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.nagelplatten.length; i++) {
   if(this.nagelplatten[i].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.warenkorb.length; i++) {
      if(this.warenkorb[i].Stk == stk && this.warenkorb[i].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
         this.warenkorb.splice(i, 1);
      }

      ...
```

What happens if you use 'k' instead of 'i' in the inner loop?

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.nagelplatten.length; i++) {
   if(this.nagelplatten[i].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
    for (let k = 0; k < this.warenkorb.length; k++) {

      if(this.warenkorb[k].Stk == stk && this.warenkorb[k].PKArtikelID == artnr) {
         this.warenkorb.splice(k, 1);
      }
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But this dosn´t work for me. I think the Problem is when i click on my expansion-panel-header how i apply the filter when i click on the same it works. But when i click the second one i become an new array from the filter. And the i click the second one the Inputfields on the articel side are empty. The Basket works perfekt.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSFUJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQrms.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOlDG.png

Comment: Has nobody an Idee? Who can i reload the array with the Filter with no destroy the data.

Comment: To be able to answer that question I'd need to see your HTML-template. Can you please provide this?

Comment: Hi, I added a new solution.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the Solution